# Possible to reorder iframes in the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have a page that has several dynamically created iframes all in a div.  I would like to dynamically reorder them within that div without refreshing them and/or losing their contentWindow.

If I try and insertBefore this doesn't work and I end up losing the content of the iframe I am trying to move.

Is there a way to do this without doing position absolute and having to set a top and a left?  I'd like to still be able to use relative positioning for simplicity if at all possible.

Comment: What about reordering them with `position: relative`?

Comment: @jan dvorak well I guess to be more clear what I meant is I want them to still be able to float left.  I don't want to have to set a left and a top and manage that because I will be adding and removing them dynamically.

Comment: You could float IFrame-sized placeholders and position (even easily animate) the IFrames over them on each reflow.

Comment: thats not bad, a bit of a hack but will probably work, thanks

Comment: Did the solution suggested by @JanDvorak work?

Answer (score 0):

The only way think of would be to set a variable equal to the iframe's contentWindow / contentDocument. Then use whatever method you want to reposition that one or delete it and create a new one, then set it's contentWindow / contentDocument to the variable that you previously stored.

---

P.S. I'm an amateur iframer so feel free t tell me if the idea's stupid, but please don't freak out about it.

Comment: Or I suppose use the previously stated `position: relative` idea and give each one a class of it's placing in the row or column of iframes. Then set they're left/top positions to their width times their class. (or that could be an id, it wouldn't matter)